# MacOs - Decompressing a large number of .gz files

Tags: macos, terminal, command, compression

I have a folder with 40,000 files, all named 1.gz > 40000.gz

I am using mac terminal to execute this in the folder

Where in my terminal I executed:

```
gunzip 1.gz
```

and it decompressed one file, then I tried to decompress all:

```
gunzip *.gz
```

but it throws:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/gunzip: Argument list too long
```

because there are too many files.

What should I do here?

Comment: Can you move half the files into a new temporary folder? Moving them is very quick. Then you can mv some from temp folder back to the original folder. Actually, the simplest method may be to create a temp folder inside the folder with the 40,000 files. Then they will be easy to move in and out.

Comment: I just ran a test and gunzip works on 12,200 files. But it didn't work for me 13,200 files so cutoff is between 12,200 and 13,200 files at once. So if you use my method you'll need to do it 1/4th at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move a fourth of the files into a new temporary folder? Moving them is very quick. Then you can move some from the temp folder back to the original folder. Actually, the simplest method may be to create a temp folder inside the folder with the 40,000 files. Then they will be easy to move in and out. Gunzip seems to work on around 12,200 files but not on 13,300 files. So doing 10,000 of your files at once should be a breeze.

Comment: @Kay, Mark Adler had a much better solution. Sorry, I didn't think of that and I hope my method didn't cause you any problems.   Sorry again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`:

```
find . -exec gunzip '{}' +
```

or you can look explicitly for files that have not been gunzipped yet:

```
find . -name \*.gz -exec gunzip '{}' +
```

Those will do it for everything in the current directory and below. If you want to restrict it to the current directory, add `-maxdepth 1` to the options.

The single quotes around the braces are so that spaces in file and directory names are properly handled. That is why `xargs` will have issues when trying to solve problems like this.